# Magento 2: Layout Update XML (Admin) Remove & Add Blocks

Tags: xml, magento, magento2

Quick Note: I have full admin access to M2 but no server access. (Magento EE 2.1.4).

So, I've got a few CMS pages that are using the layout "2 columns with left bar". The sidebar for this layout is a simple menu from a static block.

I'm trying to remove the existing menu and add a static block in its place at the page level.

A quick Google has shown me I can use something like:

```
<referenceBlock name="advice_centre_leftmenu" remove="true"/>

<referenceContainer name="sidebar">
   <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="test">
       <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">test</argument>
       </arguments>
   </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

The issue is that I have no idea what the Container or Block names are. I also don't have the relevant access to get at the PHTML files to find out that way (3rd party dev agency).

In the admin section, the block that contains the menu I'm trying to remove has the identifier "advice_leftmenu" however when I try:

```
<referenceBlock name="advice_leftmenu" remove="true"/>
```

Nothing happens.

Here is the relevant HTML that's around the sidebar:

```
<div class="columns">
    <div class="sidebar sidebar-main">
        <div class="widget block block-static-block">
            <div class="left-cms-content">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also tried the following to no effect:

```
<referenceBlock name="sidebar.sidebar-main" remove="true"/>

<referenceBlock name="sidebar-main" remove="true"/>
```

Is there somewhere in the HTML/admin I can look at to find the container/block names?

Am I going to be forced to coerce some time out of the agency to find the names for me?

**Update**:

I turned on theme hints thanks to a suggestion from @Nolwennig.

I've now managed to add the block using:

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
   <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="buyers-menu">
       <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">buyers-menu</argument>
       </arguments>
   </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

However I still can't remove the block, I now know the block id is left_cms_content. I've now also tried:

```
<referenceBlock name="left_cms_content" remove="true"/>
```

But there's still no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Enable path hints (`Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront`) and block hints (`Add Block Names to Hints`) in the admin interface:

> Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug

Comment: Thanks! I've now managed to add the block using:

`<referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
   <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="buyers-menu">
       <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">buyers-menu</argument>
       </arguments>
   </block>
</referenceContainer>`

However I still can't remove the block, I now know the block id is left_cms_content. I've now also tried:

`<referenceBlock name="left_cms_menu" remove="true"/>`

But there's still no effect.